# Render string variable that represents Html.Partial via Html.Raw

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a standard form builder control that has a `raw html` option. I want to use this control to render a `partial view` that exists in the project. This is an `MVC, Razor view`.

The control looks like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Html)
```

Model.Html will be something like

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")
```

I am looking for it to handle like this:

```
@{Model.Html = "@Html.Partial("ViewName")"}
@Html.Raw(Model.Html) aka @Html.Raw("@Html.Partial("ViewName")")
```